# show tooltip on custom marker for high stock Chart

Tags: text, highcharts, tooltip, customization

The chart i am trying to create as shown below[image]

```
 the working fiddle is as shown below 
         https://jsfiddle.net/n5k03rpu/5/
```

on hover in the  custom icon i am getting date by default is there a way to add custom text other than date in the tooltip

please point to a sample on the same

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `series.tooltip.pointFormatter`.

**Example code:**

```
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '',
      pointFormatter: function() {
        return "Custom flag: " + this.title
      }
    },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1pz28y3/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Is there any css u written to show the tool tip in top of the marker

Comment: I didn't use any css - this is the default tooltip position for flag series

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73943487/show-multiple-axis-to-highcharts-chart-and-present-axis-to-left can u please check this @magdalena