# show multiple axis to highcharts chart and present axis to left

Tags: charts, highcharts, label, axis

Trying to create a chart as show below
[image]

```
Tried to get most of it working fiddle is in 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1pz28y3/
```

But only axis is the issue. Unable to get multiple axis for different chart and also axis on the left rather than right please help me by pointing to some demo

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `yAxis.opposite` to `false`. Your image shows only two axis (first one for the line and flag series, the second one for the column), so here is the example config basing on the image:

```
yAxis: [{
  opposite: false,
  height: '60%'
}, {
  opposite: false,
  top: '65%',
  height: '40%',
  offset: 0
}],
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/at8Lyod4/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.opposite